# how to sort data according datetime using st-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have following code my data does not sort according to  datetime please help me this i am using  `<div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>` i think its show problem , check below code  i have more then 30 records that's why sorting problem

```
<table st-table='displayedAssets' st-safe-src="assetController.assetsData" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed mb-none dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9">
                <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                    Search
                    <li><input st-search="city" placeholder="City" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></li>
                    <li> <input st-search="region" placeholder="Region" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></li>
                    <li><input st-search="medium" placeholder="Medium" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" /></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>create date</th>
            <th>Location</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedAssets | orderBy:'created_date':true ">
            <td>{{ row.city }}</td>
            <th>{{ row.created_date }}</th>

            <td>{{ row.location }}</td>

            <td>
                <button type="button" title="Delete" ng-click="assetController.showConfirm($event, row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                    </i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" class="text-right">
                <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

angularjs js

```
this.$http.get('/api/assets')
      .then(response => {
        this.assetsData = response.data;     
        this.socket.syncUpdates('asset', this.assetsData);
});
```

Comment: correct me if am wrong, you have problems with sorting according to date. right?

Comment: yes............

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Date sorting

```js
let dateTimeArr = ["11/14/13 12:07","12/13/11 01:07","09/09/12 09:04","08/30/14 19:05","04/24/04 16:03","08/15/16 10:02","12/13/11 02:07"]

let sortedArr = dateTimeArr.sort((a,b)=>{
 return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime();
})

console.log(sortedArr);
```